# Joules of Energy Striking a Window Sill Daily

Tags: sun, evaporation

Roughly how many joules of energy (through sunlight) will strike a 20 centimetre tall cylindrical bottle on the 10th floor of a building daily, if the bottle is placed on a window sill facing the East? This rough estimate can be as accurate as an order of magnitude - please explain how you got to the answer, or please suggest a way I could calculate this value to the nearest order of magnitude.

P.S. I am trying to calculate how long it would take for water in a perfectly cylindrical bottle to evaporate completely.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first take the value of sunlight's energy as 100 joules per second on each square foot. You could check various values on the Web for your particular area.

You will need  to reduce this energy inflow  to fit the surface area (actually half the surface area) of your particular cylindrical bottle, assuming the bottle is left on the window sill with one half facing the Sun.

Ignoring the top and bottom of the bottle, the total surface area is  π * radius * height, for a half cylinder, which is the effective surface area facing the Sun.

Then take into account the specific heat capacity of water, that is the amount of heat needed to raise the temperature of one gram of mass by 1 kelvin. For water this is 4185.5 J/(kg⋅K) (15 °C, 101.325 kPa). This assumes the water is initially at 15 °C, so this would have to be adjusted, as presumably your water supply is at a lower temperature, but this is simply a rough estimation.

Finally, how long will the bottle be in the sun and what is the outside temperature and humidity, as this will affect the rate of evaporation?